# Is it possible to register more than one user with Asp.Net Identity core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I know by creating an user service with entity framework and creating a password hash i can add one or more users to the website! **but i'd like to use asp.net identity features** even when i want to register batch users (like upload users list with excel or xml file).
In my scenario i want register more than one users on the website by uploading users list in xml,json or excel file. **And i want to register all of them in one transaction.** 
Has anyone idea?

Comment: Do you have all of the information required to register each user in the xml/excel file? (email, password, name etc)

Comment: Yes, I have, it is an intranet application. At the first time all users must be registered by the admin with default username and password.

Answer (score 5):

Depends at what level of abstraction you want to work at, but by just looping over the content of the default Register method, you could do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterLotsOfPeople(RegisterLotsModel model)
{
    var successful = new List<string>();
    var failed = new List<string>();
    foreach (var toRegister in model.ApplicationUsers)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = toRegister.UserName, Email = toRegister.Email};
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, toRegister.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            successful.Add(toRegister.UserName);
        }
        else
        {
            failed.Add(toRegister.UserName);
        }
    }

    return Json(new {SuccessfullyRegistered = successful, FailedToRegister = failed});
}
```

You'd have to post the data to the end point in JSON format.

The DTO classes are:

```
public class RegisterLotsModel
{
    public List<UserToRegister> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}

public class UserToRegister
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

There's lots of other way to do what you're trying to achieve, but this is quick, dirty and would likely work fine. You may need to send the confirmation email in the success part of the method, if email confirmation is required.

## Edit - Single Transaction

To insert all the new users in one transaction, you would have to generate their password hashes first, and then insert them into the database.

To get a hash of a given password, you can use the password hasher provided by the `UserManager`:

```
foreach (var toRegister in model.ApplicationUsers)
{
    var hasher = _userManager.PasswordHasher;
    var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = toRegister.UserName, Email = toRegister.Email};
    toRegister.Hashed = hasher.HashPassword(user, toRegister.Password);
}
```

You could then manually insert these into the database. This would be enough for basic password authentication, but if your implementation uses things like SecurityStamp, you would likely need to implement the appropriate methods when creating the user.

Comment: In your code, each user will be registered in separate transactions, but i want add all of them in only one transaction!  is it possible in asp.net identity?

Comment: Yes, but you’d need to do the password hashing in code, then insert the users in sql. This is definitely possible in asp.net identity, but I haven’t tried it in core. I believe the password hasher is available through the usermanager. I’m out right now- will have a look when I get home.

Comment: Thank you, yes, even i can attach all created user models in dbcontext and then call savechanges method. But, in my case the presentation layer can't access to data access layer(dbcontext), and for each entity i have one data service provider in data service layer(like CommentsService) and i don't like to create any data service provider for users or rols because i using asp.net identity and they have.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to include a way to do this in a single transaction

Comment: Thank you.I think Asp.net identity don't have any approach to this case. and as you said users will added manually to the database.

Comment: @isaeid, is it worth saving multiple users manually in a single transaction? or its equivalent in performance with `usermanager.CreateAsync()` ?

Comment: `@HamzaKhanzada, Actually no, because the program was written for an organization, my goal was to get a list of members from one source and register them all at once. I knew it was possible to insert directly to the database, but I also wanted the webmaster to be able to register a list of people together.

Comment: What would the razor side of this look like??

Comment: @JacobHallgarth That would very much depend on how you want it to work. The important bit for submitting the list of `UserToRegister` models is making sure to enumerate the names for the form controls. For example, the first username field in the razor form should have the name `ApplicationUsers[0].UserName`, the second one should have the name `ApplicationUsers[1].UserName`... etc. Just use JS or jquery to insert new form inputs within the form as you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm not sure if it's a problem with my javascript. Would you mind having a look for me, if it isn't too much trouble? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61377847/registering-multiple-users-using-same-form-net-identity