# Registering multiple users using same form .net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a dynamic in line form in my ASP.NET MVC application, which when a user clicks a button, in this case 'add', it will add a new row to the form with the required fields. I am trying to get this to work with ASP.Net Identity, but not having any luck.

I believe it would be similar to having a list, and then doing a for a loop  through the list to register the users, but putting it into practice is proving to be confusing.

```
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="">    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group mx-1">
            <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
            <input name="Email" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-1">
            <label class="control-label" for="User_Role">User Role</label>
            <select name="UserRoles" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The UserRoles field is required." id="UserRoles" ><option value="">Role</option>
<option value="Employee">Employee</option>
<option value="Manager">Manager</option>
</select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-1">
            <label class="control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
            <input name="Password" class="form-control valid validate-equalTo-blur" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value=""aria-describedby="Password-error" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-1">
            <label class="control-label" for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
            <input class="form-control valid" name="ConfirmPassword" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" value="" aria-describedby="ConfirmPassword-error" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info add_button form-control col-md-1" style="margin-top: 37px"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
```

```
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div class="form-group row">
<fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
   <input name="Email" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="User_Role">User Role</label>
   <select name="UserRoles" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The UserRoles field is required." id="UserRoles" ><option value="">Role</option>
   <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
   <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
   <input name="Password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password"  placeholder="Password" type="text" value="">
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
   <input name="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="text" value="">
</fieldset>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button form-control col-md-1" style="margin-top: 37px"><i class="fas fa-times center"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info my-2">Submit</button>
   <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning my-2 ml-1" href="/Home">Back</a>
</div>
```

Jquery Form:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed - change as needed
    var wrapper = $(".field_wrapper"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_button"); // class add button
    var remove_button = $('.remove_button'); // class remove button

    var html = `
    <div class="form-group row">
        <fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Email" })
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
            @Html.Label("User Role", new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.DropDownList("UserRoles", (SelectList)ViewBag.Name, "Role", new { @class = "form-control"})
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Password" })
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group mx-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder="Confirm Password" })
        </fieldset>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button form-control col-md-1" style="margin-top: 37px"><i class="fas fa-times center"></i></a>
    </div>`;

    var x = 1; //initlal count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; // increment value of x
            $('.counter').text(x);
            $(wrapper).append(html); //add html
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", remove_button, function (e) { // runs when a user clicks on anything with the class 'remove_button'
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default, duh
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); // get parent of each element and remove it
        x--; // decrement the value of x
        $('.counter').text(x); // update text with the count only after value of x has been changed
    })
});
```

My AccountController method - I have an employee class which inherits the identity model and also uses its own view model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterEmployees(EmployeeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, will you edit your `var html` to contain the HTML generated result? We're going to need to replace a few html attributes.

Comment: Yep, I've edited to show what the html generated result would be when a user clicks the 'add' button.

Comment: The name attribute is generated in the input fields, you might have to scroll to the right to see it though as .net inserts a lot of attributes. I will edit the OP to make it easier to see.

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks! found it. Hang on, making an an answer

Comment: you used to have a script earlier, will you include that, thanks!

Comment: yep, i've added it again now :)

Comment: @JacobHallgarth I had a quick look. Don't use `@Html.TextBoxFor` within your JS. Just code that bit with regular html. Or if you really want to use razor for that bit, make a partial view and a new endpoint that you pass your index (I think you called it `x`) and it'll return the correct HTML for that index. In the partial view use `@Html.TextBox` rather than `TextBoxFor` and specify the name that way. I'll see if I can find a few mins later to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the previous answer to this would work, but you commented on [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361334/1867541) asking to look at this question, so here you go:

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible, so you're gonna have to add in your own extra markup, styling, data annotations etc.

## Models

Pretty self explanatory, we just have a model for the view that has a list of user models.

```cs
public class RegisterLotsModel
{
    public List<UserToRegister> UsersToRegister { get; set; }
}

public class UserToRegister
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

## View

Just a simple form with some inputs for the fields to register the users. The surrounding divs are referenced in the JS and are used when we append the HTML for the extra users.

```
@model BulkRegister.Models.RegisterLotsModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("BulkRegister"))
{
    <div class="users-to-register">
        <div class="user-container">
            <input type="text" name="UsersToRegister[0].UserName" />
            <input type="email" name="UsersToRegister[0].Email" />
            <input type="password" name="UsersToRegister[0].Password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="add-user-button" value="Add another user" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register the users" />
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/bulk-reg.js"></script>
}
```

## JQuery

I put this in a separate file, but you can just pop it at the bottom of the view if you like. We count how many `user-container` classes are already on the page to work out what the index for the HTML we're adding should be. This means we don't have to keep track with a separate variable.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#add-user-button').click(function () {

        // how many users are there already
        var userContainerCount = $('.user-container').length;

        // this count is used for the index for the next user container
        var nextIndex = userContainerCount;

        // build up some html. it's far simpler to just use regular html here, rather than razor.
        // if you really want to use razor then look into partial views and fetching via ajax.
        // you could use es6 backticks here to create a multi line string, but there seemed to 
        // be a little confusion in the comments, so this is just a plain concatenated string.
        var html = '<div class="user-container">' +
            '<input type="text" name="UsersToRegister[' + nextIndex + '].UserName" />' +
            '<input type="email" name="UsersToRegister[' + nextIndex + '].Email" />' +
            '<input type="password" name="UsersToRegister[' + nextIndex + '].Password" />' +
            '</div>';

        // append the html
        $('.users-to-register').append(html);

    });

});
```

## Controller Actions

GET: Nothing fancy.

```cs
public ActionResult BulkRegister()
{
    return View();
}
```

POST: Loop over the users in the model and just register them with the UserManager. You'll need to add validation and whatever you want to do to report successes and failures.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> BulkRegister(RegisterLotsModel model)
{
    // do whatever validation you want
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    // loop over your users and register them in the regular way
    var successful = new List<string>();
    var failed = new List<string>();
    foreach (var toRegister in model.UsersToRegister)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = toRegister.UserName, Email = toRegister.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, toRegister.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            successful.Add(toRegister.UserName);
        else
            failed.Add(toRegister.UserName);
    }

    // do whatever you want to do with failures
    if (failed.Any())
        return RedirectToAction("FailedRegistration", new { failed });

    // maybe register some more users?
    return RedirectToAction("BulkRegister");
}
```

And that's it. If you've got a lot of users to register you might want to just build up the user models and [insert them straight into the database in a single transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361334/1867541).

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a View model that will house the list of type UserViewModel. I used `EmployeeListViewModel`;

```
public class EmployeeListViewModel{
   public List<EmployeeViewModel> UsersToRegister {get;set;}
}
```

2. Change the model declaration on the top of your view to;

```
@model EmployeeListViewModel
```

3. Use this for your form. We need to define the input fields statically because we need to use the 0 index on the name like `Model.UsersToRegister[0].Email`;

```
// please edit with your parameters
@Html.BeginForm(){

// add validate forgery token html helper

<div class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label>
   <input name="Model.UsersToRegister[0].Email" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="User_Role">User Role</label>
   <select name="Model.UsersToRegister[0].UserRoles" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The UserRoles field is required." id="UserRoles" >
      <option value="">Role</option>
      <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
      <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
   <input name="Model.UsersToRegister[0].Password" class="form-control valid validate-equalTo-blur" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value=""aria-describedby="Password-error" aria-invalid="false">
</div>
<div class="form-group mx-1">
   <label class="control-label" for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
   <input class="form-control valid" name="Model.UsersToRegister[0].ConfirmPassword" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" value="" aria-describedby="ConfirmPassword-error" aria-invalid="false">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info add_button form-control col-md-1" style="margin-top: 37px"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>

}
```

4. Update your script to use this, what we did here is we're using `x` as a counter. The counter will indicate which index (in a list of objects) does a certain input field belong to;

```
<script>

var x = 1; //initlal count
$(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add button click
   e.preventDefault();
   if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed

      var html = "
         <div class='field_wrapper'>
            <div class='form-group row'>
               <fieldset class='form-group mx-1'>
                  <label class='control-label' for='Email'>Email</label>
                  <input name='Model.UsersToRegister["+x+"].Email' class='form-control' data-val='true' data-val-email='The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.' data-val-required='The Email field is required.' id='Email' placeholder='Email' type='text' value=''>
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset class='form-group mx-1'>
                  <label class='control-label' for='User_Role'>User Role</label>
                  <select name='Model.UsersToRegister["+x+"].UserRoles' class='form-control' data-val='true' data-val-required='The UserRoles field is required.' id='UserRoles' ><option value=''>Role</option>
                     <option value='Employee'>Employee</option>
                     <option value='Manager'>Manager</option>
                  </select>
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset class='form-group mx-1'>
                  <label class='control-label' for='Password'>Password</label>
                  <input name='Model.UsersToRegister["+x+"].Password' class='form-control' data-val='true' data-val-length='The Password must be at least 6 characters long.' data-val-length-max='100' data-val-length-min='6' data-val-required='The Password field is required.' id='Password'  placeholder='Password' type='text' value=''>
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset class='form-group mx-1'>
                  <label class='control-label' for='ConfirmPassword'>Confirm password</label>
                  <input name='Model.UsersToRegister["+x+"].ConfirmPassword' class='form-control' data-val='true' data-val-equalto='The password and confirmation password do not match.' data-val-equalto-other='*.Password' id='ConfirmPassword' placeholder='Confirm Password' type='text' value=''>
               </fieldset>
               <a href='#' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button form-control col-md-1' style='margin-top: 37px'><i class='fas fa-times center'></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
     ";

      x++; // increment value of x
      $('.counter').text(x);
      $(wrapper).append(html); //add html
   }
});

</script>
```

5. Then use this for your controller action, we replaced the parameter with the new class;

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterEmployees(EmployeeListViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      foreach(var u in model.UsersToRegister){
         var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = u.Email, Email = u.Email };
         var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, u.Password);

         if(!result.Succeeded){
            break; // depends on you if you want to stop creating users if one failed
            // continue; // depends on you if you want to continue creating users if one failed
         }
      }

      if (result.Succeeded)
      {
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
      AddErrors(result);
   }

   // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: In your view, when removing certain row from your user list, you might need to customize your remove script so that it would reorder the indexes on the name attribute.

Comment: Hey thanks, this can help, however this one creates some issues in the compiler. 1. Razor doesn't know what 'x' is and I can't put it in a string because it's a list index

Comment: @Jacob oh i got it, hang on. It's the single quote and double quote conflicts

Comment: @JacobHallgarth I updated the answer, in `var html = " ";` there was a conflict with single quote and double quotes, hence javascript doesn't know which one are variables and which one are static content. Try copying the whole script as is.

Comment: I'm getting an error for the list index, "Cannot convert string to int". I tried changing the string around to apostrophes instead, but that converts 'x' to the ASCII decimal value. As for the javascript string is, I used the ES6 backtick because it is used for template strings. Changing the strings to an apostrophe will cause an error for C#, because there are too many characters for it to convert to ASCII.

Comment: string to int-- Which line is that error from exactly? Did you copy the script as is?

Comment: ["+x+"] in this part here, I use @Model.UsersToRegister["+x+"].ConfirmPassword eg

Comment: @JacobHallgarth ohh i believe thats incorrect, we need to pass everything statically. It has to be a static text, so no need for `@`. Try to completely copy the script, including the script tag.

Comment: Hmm, still not working for me. I have made a repo if you want to look further into it. https://github.com/ubisales-jacob/OMS-Dev

Comment: @JacobHallgarth `https://github.com/ubisales-jacob/OMS-Dev/blob/master/OMS-Dev/Views/Account/RegisterEmployee.cshtml` in this file, `var x = 1` should be before `var html` assignment.

Comment: @JacobHallgarth then please copy the `var html` from my answer.

Comment: This one also works too. Problem I was having, is that the 'x' value wasn't being updated, I used @Erresen's answer to help me with that.

Comment: It's fine, i upvoted his answer, nice that u have it working